# Galois group of $(x^3-2)(x^5-1)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I am studying for my Galois theory final for tomorrow (and I'm really getting burned out), I need help with the following question:

> Galois group $G$ of $f(x)=(x^3-2)(x^5-1)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}$ and let $\omega_3$ be the primitive cubed root of unity, and $\omega_5$ the primitive $5$th root of unity. The splitting field for $f$ is $E=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega_3, \omega_5)$. We know that $E:\mathbb{Q}$ is separable since $\text{char}\mathbb{Q}=0$ and that it is normal since it is a splitting field. Hence $E:\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois. So $|G|=|E:\mathbb{Q}|$. It is easy for me to show that $\text{Gal}((x^3-2)/\mathbb{Q}) \cong S_3$ and that $\text{Gal}((x^5-1)/\mathbb{Q}) \cong C_4$.

But how can I determine $\text{Gal}(f)$? How can I find the size of the extension $|E:\mathbb{Q}|$? I know it is divisible by $6$ and $4$.

Edit: I see people mentioning the result about cartesian products. I have not seen this  result. Given that this is a past exam question I would be interested in a proof that does not use the result

Comment: Do you know the degrees of the cyclotomic extensions? If you know that $[\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{15}):\Bbb{Q}]=8$, and that the extension is abelian, then you are basically done.

Comment: The splitting fields of $x^3-2$ and $x^5-1$ are linearly disjoint, so $G$ is the product of their Galois groups.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I know both of those facts. But why is that the case?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown hm, never saw that results. The past papers I'm doing are from a different lecturer so seems like it was not covered this year.

Comment: The extension generated by both $\omega_3$ and $\omega_5$ is the same extension you get by adjoining $\omega_{15}$. Do you see why? Then $8$ is coprime to $3$. That is enough to give you the degree. I first thought that you need to use the fact that the cyclotomic extension is abelian to deduce that $\root3\of2\notin\Bbb{Q}(\omega_{15})$, but that was an error.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see how the result follows. If you give an answer on why those extensions are the same I will accept it and will be very grateful

Comment: I think that fact has been explained somewhere on the site, so I should not post that step as an answer. I want you to work it out. Hint: Why is $\omega_3\omega_5$ of order fifteen?

Comment: I got it, thank you for the help. To see $(w_3w_5)^{15}=1$ is easy. To see its $\neq 1$ for $n<15$ its just congruences. If you post any answer from the comments I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

The Galois group of $f=gh$ is equal to the cartesian product of the Galois group of $g$ and the Galois group of $h$ iff the splitting field of $g$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is disjoint with the splitting field of $h$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I.e. you have to determine whether $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_3,\sqrt[3]{2})\cap\mathbb{Q}(\omega_5)=\mathbb{Q}$. If shown, you have that Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(\omega_3,\sqrt[3]{2},\omega_5)/\mathbb{Q})\cong S_3\times C_4$.